# ConfigurationManager not saving in VS2012 after exit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, configurationmanager

I have a c# application that saves settings using ConfigurationManager, like this:

```
    public static void SaveSetting(string key, string value)
    {
        var configurationFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        configurationFile.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
        configurationFile.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
        configurationFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    }
```

Running from a compiled .exe, everything is fine - application_name.exe.Config contains the updated settings.

Running out of VS2012, application_name.vshost.exe.Config gets saved properly by SaveSetting(). But as soon as I exit the application, application_name.vshost.exe.Config reverts back to what it was before I started the application - even the time stamp shows it's the old version of the config file.

What's going on ?

Answer (score 0):

vshost.exe.config is just for use while debugging.  It is not intended to have its values persisted. As soon as you stop running the application it is replaced by the exe.config file.

Comment: Thanks ! That makes sense, even if it's not the way I would have done it :)